# Show that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at origin given conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Suppose that $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, and let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ be such that
>
> 1. $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$
> 2. $f$ is continuous at $0$
> 3. $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) \to 0$$ as $x\to 0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.
>      Show that $f$ is differentiable at origin.

Surely if $f$ was differentiable at origin, partial derivatives would exist there and the conditions given suggests that (maybe) these partial derivatives are $0$ at the origin, so that they are continuous at the origin, implying differentiability. To this end I need to show that if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are standard basis elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then

$$
\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(te_i)-f(0)}{t}=0
$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g_{i}:R\rightarrow R$ defined by $g_{i}(t)=f(0,0,\cdots ,t,0,0,\cdots )$ where $t$ is in the $i$th position. Then $g_{i}$ is continuous on $[0,t]$ and differentiable in $(0,t)$ so the MVT applies and we may write $$\frac{f(te_i)-f(0)}{t}=\frac{g_{i}(t)-g_{i}(0)}{t}=g'_{i}(c)$$ for some $c\in (0,t)$. But $$g'_{i}(c)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(0,0,\cdots c,0,0\cdots )$$ Now let $t\rightarrow 0$, so that $c\rightarrow 0$.

Then, by assumption $$g'_{i}(c)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(0,0,\cdots c,0,0\cdots )\rightarrow 0$$ and the result follows.